# Rails performance with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I have a Rails 4 application.

A Rails application contains :

- an `application.js` file
- a `my_model.js` file for each visible model
- a `my_model/action.html` file for each action.

In all of theses files, I can write some `javascript`. My issue is that I don't know where to put javascript code. The most problematic issue is that putting javascript into `my_model/action.html` seems to be the best place for javascript needed just for this action, but is not compiled and not sent with the generated `application.js` file in production mode.

Is there any *rule* or *best practice* for putting javascript into theses files ?

Regards

Comment: It will be better to put your code in `app/assets/Javascripts/application,js` it will be available all of your page within the application.

Comment: check [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you creating controllers via `rails g controller` it will also create parallel .coffee files of the same name, use them for that controller#actions.
In production they'll all be compiled into one script. BTW the generated .coffee says:

> Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller
>   here.  All this logic will automatically be available in
>   application.js. ...